# Update regression formula to exclude interaction term(s) in R?

Tags: r, function, regression

As part of a function I am writing, I'd like to re-run a regression without any interaction term(s) that are present, but maintaining the main effects from those interactions. My goal is to have one line of code that works with objects from lm, glm, lmer, lmerTest, glmer, glmmTMB, etc. (For broader context, this portion of the function relates to checking for collinearity. If a model includes interaction terms, I like to check for collinearity without those terms. I am using check_collinearity {performance}.)

First I store fixed effects in a variable. "out" is the model object that was passed in to the function. This works as expected.
`out.fixvars <- attr(terms(out), which="term.labels")`

The following works for fixed effects models, but with random effects models it removes the random effect.
`out.noint <- update(out, formula=drop.terms(terms(out), grep('[:]', out.fixvars), keep.response=T))`

This code works with fixed effect models, but with random effects models it keeps the random effect.
`out.noint <- update(out, . ~ . -out.fixvars[grep('[:]', out.fixvars)])`

How can I achieve my goal? Ideally I'd like one line that works on multiple model types, but if I have to use separate methods for different model types I can incorporate that. Related answers I found involve typing out the specific interaction term, but I am trying to automate this so that all interaction terms are removed without the user needing to specify them by name.

EDIT: Adding minimum reproducible example

```
out <- lmer(abundance~prop_seminatural*flower_richness+bare_ground+(1|site), data=TXdata)
```

I actually pass a regression object into the variable "out" in the function, but locally assigning it and running the code below produces the same problem. This is the portion of the function that contains the problematic line of code.

```
require(easystats)

#Collinearity----
    #Store model fixed effect terms in a variable
    out.fixvars <- attr(terms(out), which="term.labels")
```

out.fixvars contains "prop_seminatural", "flower_richness, "bare_ground" and "prop_seminatural:flower_richness"

```
    #Check for collinearity if there is more than one fixed effect
    if (length(out.fixvars) > 1)
    {
        cat("Collinearity in original model?", "\n", "\n")
        print(check_collinearity(out))
        #Collinearity without interaction terms
        cat("\n", "\n", "Collinearity with interaction term(s) removed?", "\n", "\n")
        out.noint <- update(out, . ~ . -out.fixvars[grep('[:]', out.fixvars)])
        print(check_collinearity(out.noint))
    }
```

`formula(out.noint)` gives
abundance~prop_seminatural+flower_richness+bare_ground+(1|site)+prop_seminatural:flower_richness

My update() call has not removed the interaction term.

The other thing I tried was replacing the above update line with
`out.noint <- update(out, formula=drop.terms(terms(out), grep('[:]', out.fixvars), keep.response=T))`

The random effect gets removed, which also means that lmer returns, "Error: no random effects terms specified in formula". To demonstrate the issue I ran just
`formula=drop.terms(terms(out), grep('[:]', attr(terms(out), which="term.labels"))`

The resulting formula is ~prop_seminatural+flower_richness+bare_ground

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: (P.S. Ben Bolker, the portion of this function that prints model outputs follows the recommendations on your GLMM wiki. Thanks for providing that great resource!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly but I think it works:

```r
## retrieve interaction terms 
int_terms <- grep(":", out.fixvars, value = TRUE)
## minus-separated values
all_int_terms <- paste(sprintf("-%s", int_terms), collapse = " ")
## formula  (reformulate() doesn't work)
upform <- formula(sprintf(". ~ . %s", all_int_terms))
out.noint <- update(out, upform)
```

```r
names(fixef(out.noint))
[1] "(Intercept)"      "prop_seminatural" "flower_richness"  "bare_ground"
```

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker! I successfully tested with lm (1 or 2 interaction terms), glm.nb, lmer (1 or 2 interaction terms), and glmer.nb.  I also tried with a glmmTMB model object (with the default gaussian family) with the same original formula as the above LMM. update() outputs a warning: "In fitTMB(TMBStruc) : Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')". Perhaps related to this [conversation re. update.glmmTMB](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/341)? I am running a slightly old version of glmmTMB (1.1.5) due to install issues.

Comment: Is there any reason to ignore the most obvious possibility, i.e. that the updated model (with the removed terms) has some convergence issues? Have you tried `diagnose()` ?

Comment: Oops, yes that was the issue. I now have the function that returns the error within try() so the entire function will still run (and notify the user that there is a problem) even if there are convergence issues. Good to know about diagnose(), too.